# Stop laptop keys acting as a numpad with numlock on

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, laptop, key-mapping

I have bought an [USB number pad](http://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B000OZ65EG/) and it's working as expected. Anyway, to use number keys, I need num lock on, and if I turn it on, my [keyboard numpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM0J6.jpg) sends numbers instead of the letters... How to have letter keys with num pad on?

If that matters, I'm on an Asus eee PC 900 and using the lastest Linux Mint Debian Edition.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should adjust you keyboard settings "keyboard model" in "system settings". Or edit the file: `/etc/default/keyboard`.

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and there many options to choose.

Comment: I google it, found this **should try a [Shift + Num Lock]** on this (http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Debian/2009-03/msg00008.html).